# Mutation return null on signup

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, graphql, typeorm

I'm building an API with graphql, typegraphql and typeorm using typescript and I have my signup mutation who returns null when I return the user but it return the errors without problem.
I precise that when I use the signup mutation the user is correctly saved in the databse (I use postgres) and I can console.log the result of the query

signup mutation:

```
@Mutation((_) => UserResponse)
  async signup(
    @Arg('email') email: string,
    @Arg('password') password: string
  ): Promise<UserResponse> {
    const errors = await signupValidation(email, password);

    if (errors.length > 0) {
      return { errors };
    }

    const result = await getConnection()
      .createQueryBuilder()
      .insert()
      .into(User)
      .values([{ email, password }])
      .returning('*')
      .execute();
    console.log(result.raw[0])
    return result.raw[0];
  }
```

the console.log's result
[image]

And here is me calling the mutation (no errors)
[image]

And here is the result where there is an error
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your function is returning a `User`-shaped object, not a `UserResponse` (with `user` and `errors` properties).

Change your code to

```
return { user: result.raw[0] };
```

(and maybe try to figure out why TypeScript didn't complain - is `result` typed as `any`?)

Comment: Thanks it was the correct answer and I think typescript didn't complain because thre result was also an object with the same shape